# Firebase Token Multiple Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've an android app that connects to two Firebase databases. If i update my token in both databases, is it possible to send notification to my app using that common token.

Or is it like there will be different token for different databases.

Comment: If the corresponding app servers are enabled to send a message to that token, then it should be fine.

Comment: I've two different firebase projects. I've an X android app added in A project and same X android app in B Project. I've a token generated using A project. If i send notification to that token from B Project, it is giving error. Can you tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a FCM message for a token created for project A you need to provide the FCM Server Key for that project A.